# Add a new field from an object in a DQL query

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

Actually I'm using something like that in DQL (Doctrine) in a Symfony2 / twig / Doctrine project:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('
                SELECT e, l
                FROM FrontendBundle:Entrega e
                JOIN e.libro l
                WHERE EXISTS (SELECT r1.id FROM FrontendBundle:Reserva r1
                                WHERE r1.entrega = e.id)'
                );
```

Look at I'm filtering the `entrega`'s that appear in some `Reserva.entrega` field. 
There is an OPTIONAL *OneToOne* relation in `Entrega`.

The `SELECT e, l` it's useful for me, because I use code like that in twig:  `{{ entrega.libro.id }}` ...

The question is if exists another way to select ALL the `Entrega`s, but having a new field in each one of them that contains the associated `Reserva` object, or null.

Something like:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('
                SELECT e, l        
             **(SELECT r1.id FROM FrontendBundle:Reserva r1
                        WHERE r1.entrega = e.id) as myReserva**

                FROM FrontendBundle:Entrega e
                JOIN e.libro l;
```

This solution doesn't work for me because the extra-select makes that the result becomes a rectangular `Array`, no and `Array` of `Entrega` Objects.
I would like:

```
{{  entrega.myEntrega }}
```

after the consult.

I know that this situation needs a `ManyToMany` relation. But my project is next to finish, and this is a new function. I want to reuse all my twig views and logic with a few changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way you can achieve this is to simply join your `Reserva` entity to the select.

For this you will have to map an association in your `Entrega` entity, called for example: `reserva`.

Then you can simply run the following query:

```
$query = $em->createQuery('
            SELECT e, l, r
            FROM FrontendBundle:Entrega e
            JOIN e.libro l
            LEFT JOIN e.reserva r'
            );
```

Only `Reserva` entities for which a relation exists in `Entrega` will be added to the result set.

Comment: Well, this works like a regular JOIN with a  ManyToMany relation.
But I'm looking for a way to mantain all the Entregas in the result set. Each one will have a entrega.reserva object, or a null if not exist.

Comment: In the query above you are maintaining all the `Entregas` in the result set, that is what the `LEFT JOIN` does. The query selects all `Entregas` and sets as null the `Entrega.reserva` property if a related `Reserva` doesn't exist.

Comment: Please note that the simple `JOIN` used for `e.libro` defaults to a `inner join`. This means that only entries in both `Entrega` and `Libro` tables will appear in the result set.

Comment: Ok. I know the JOIN and LEFT JOIN meanings. But before I don't understand your words in the correct way: "Only Reserva entities for which a relation exists in Entrega will be added to the result set". Good solution. Easy!! Thanks